# Can I use FastApi instead of drf to make APIs for my Django projects?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, fastapi

For example, I want to make e-commerce website which I am using Django for backend and I need to make API for connecting backend with front-end. Can I use Fast-API instead of DRF to do it? Or is it better to use DRF?

I want to use Fast-API because it is much faster than Django Rest Framework

Comment: what is the performance requirement for you ? is frontend server is seperate ? or it is just a static ? you want to use fastapi as intermediate server which connect the froontend and backend ?

Comment: yes frontend server is separate and I want to use React JS for frontend and I want to use fastapi as intermediate server which connect the frontend and backend

Comment: you can make such thing

Comment: Why would that not be possible? After all DRF just routes requests, etc. You can implement any logic to map from a request to a response object.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that even if it could be possible, it is not recommended.

In fact, to take full advantage of FastAPI async capabilities you have to run it with an ASGI server (like `uvicorn`), and unfortunately Django Rest Framework doesn't currently support async views or serializers.

There are some attempts to add basic async support to DRF in a few packages, but it is still experimental, and provides no guarantee of future compatibility :

- https://github.com/em1208/adrf
- https://github.com/hisdream86/drf-async-view

However I would advise you to try Django Ninja which is a Django REST API framework heavily inspired by FastAPI. It runs asynchronously with ASGI and offers much better performance than DRF for slow operations. It is also production ready :
https://github.com/vitalik/django-ninja